# Browser's tab going in infinite loading while opening a php file

Tags: php, browser, load, infinite

I'm working on IntelliJ IDEA, I have made a php file. For starting,  the php file runs fine on browser few times.  As I have connected the file to phpMyAdmin, I get some errors. While solving that errors, I need to refresh the page again and again. After refreshing for 3-4 times, the php file doesn't loads and go in infinite redirecting while all other pages works fine except the page with .php extension. The same problem occurs on each browser. When I completely close the IDE and browser and starts again,  it works. And after refreshing few times it goes again to infinite load. Where is the problem?

Comment: In your code. Pls paste it the relevant pieces.

Comment: <?php if($dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb') ;{echo "connected"} else {echo " failed"}?> take it for instance. But any file with php extension don't open, even if it don't have a single piece of php code.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your _formatted_ code. The code you just pasted is not valid PHP code.